# How to get Meteor.user() values from backend server?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have two meteor app using database for frontend and backend. Due to some bulk operation. frontend app calls backend server. works fine in many methods. in few method I should check authentication.

**frontend**

```
let remote = DDP.connect(<url>);
remote.call('methodName',argument, function(err,res){

});
```

**backend**

```
Meteor.methods({
  methodName: function(argument) {
    Meteor.user() // null value
  }
});
```

How secure suppose I send `userId` as parameter?

Comment: Use `this.userId`, see https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-userId

Comment: @AdrianLiaw `this.userId` is `null`. because its on backend server

Answer (score 1):

You have to login in a way or another.
You can do something like this:

```
var remote = DDP.connect(url);
result = remote.call('login', {
   user: user,
   password: {digest: SHA256(password), algorithm: 'sha-256' }
});
```

Sources: 
https://forums.meteor.com/t/different-interfaces-based-on-devices/264

Comment: if so, can I use other methods which is in frontend?

Comment: You have to use 2 ddp connection. Meteor.call is just a wrap on DDP class. So you can have how many ddp connection you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can get user data on server-side by:

```
var userData = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
```